# Отцентрировать дочернее окно по родительскому winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

Есть окно редактирования данных на котором расположены кнопки для вызова дочерних окон. Каким образом, можно при вызове дочернего окна отцентрировать его в соответствии размеров родительского окна и заблокировать родительское.

Comment: Делай его просто модальным, и в конструктор передавай позицию родительского, и с нее уже посчитаешься центр.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> отцентрировать его в соответствии размеров родительского окна

Установите свойству [`StartPosition`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.startposition?view=netframework-4.8) значение `CenterParent`:

```
childForm.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent;
```

> и заблокировать родительское.

Показывайте дочернее окно в режиме диалога при помощи [`ShowDialog`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.showdialog?view=netframework-4.8):

```
childForm.ShowDialog();
```